# React re-rendering a component on prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How I think/understood was that react components update whenever their props or state change.

So I declare my variable:

```
let percentage = {
  width: '10%',
};
```

and have a `setInterval` function running to change that variable after so long:

```
setInterval(function() {
  percentage = {
    width: '50%',
  };
}, 5000);
```

and below this I render my component:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render((
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Start percentage={percentage} />} />
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        <Modal />
      </div>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

Where I display the percentage in another file that looks like:

```
export default class Start extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="meter orange">
          <span style={this.props.percentage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My component never updates though, I have put a `console.log` into the `setInterval` function and get the update variable back but it never refreshes my component.

Have I misunderstood how props updates work?

Comment: Assigning a new value to the *variable* `percentage` cannot magically update the *prop* `percentage`. That's not how JavaScript works. Here is a simplified version of the problem: `var foo = 42; var component = {foo: foo}; foo = 21; console.log(component.foo);` still logs the first value `foo` had, `42`.

Comment: Sorry me being stupid :) How would I go around updating the value so it updates the prop as well and rerenders the component? @FelixKling

Comment: you could make percentage a part of your state and use setState

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about react router or meteor to help you here. Usually, if you want to update the props of the root component, you simply call `ReactDOM.render` again. As aw04 suggests, the value might have to live somewhere else.

Comment: @aw04 yeah that's what I was reading, but I do the setInterval from outside of the component and I read it's back practise for a component to update it's own props, So i've been trying to get the parent to pass down the props, and update the props so it re-renders the child

Comment: You need to tell the state to change your props and that needs to be done in your `setState` function.

Comment: You can still pass it down, I meant do it in the state of the parent controller and pass it down as percentage={this.state.percentage}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters passed to a component are copied by *value*, not reference.  So when you render the outermost component, you're passing the *current value* of `percentage` into the `Start` component:

```
<Start percentage={percentage} />
```

From the perspective of the `Start` component, its property never changes, even though the variable that provided its initial value is.

You can't be clever and try to get around this with an object that contains a property `percentage` either...because the object (the parameter itself) won't change, only its properties.

So what's a poor programmer to do?

It's a bit misleading to say that a component updates when its properties change; components actually update *when they're re-rendered*.  Very often, this happens because the enclosing (parent) component's state changes (or its been re-rendered) and it will be passing new props down to the inner component.  The solution in your case is to make `percentage` part of the state of the enclosing component.  So you would have something like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props, ...args) {
    super(props, ...args)
    this.state = { percentage: { width: '0%' } }
    setInterval(() => this.setState({ percentage: { width: '50%' } }), 5000)
  }
  render() {
    return <Start percentage={this.state.percentage} />
  }
}
```

It's technically *correct* that a component updates when its props change; however, the only way to change its props is to re-render it!  Props are read-only inside a component.  Which is why I say it's misleading (or incomplete) to think about prop changes driving component re-rendering.

Comment: Honestly, man, thanks for such a well explained response. You've explained why it wasn't working as well as how I'd go about getting it to work. Wish I could upvote you more. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help!  React is a great platform, but takes some getting used to!

Comment: Excellent answer! Currently learning React too so very helpful!

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between Component update and re-render?