# How does React know to render component when non prop or state variable changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following code for a navigation link which more or less simply handles displaying an active state.

This is working perfectly! My question is: Why? As you can see, I'm checking if the link should be active based on the window.location.pathname matching the url for this link. Inside the render function, I check if this link is active (when calling activeIndicator()).

It seems to be the case that anytime window.location.pathname updates, this re-renders. Is React's lifecycle method shouldComponentUpdate() being updated somehow when there's any change to a variable inside the component? It might be worth noting that I am using React Router in my application and clicking a link does trigger React Router.

Is doing this unsafe or fragile? Would it necessarily be better to track state in a container? Or manually override shouldComponentUpdate()?

Any information around how this is 'magically' working is much appreciated!

Thanks!

```
const Navlink = ({text, url}) => {

  const isActive = () => {
    return window.location.pathname === url;
  }

  const activeIndicator = () => {
    if( isActive() ) {
      return (
        <div className="active-indicator">
          <svg height="6" width="6">
            <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="black" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  }

  return (
    <span className="navbar-link">
      <Link to={ url } style={ (isActive()) ? {color:"black"} : {} }>
        { text }
      </Link>
      { activeIndicator() }
    </span>
  );
}
```

**Update**

To understand the answer better, it might help to understand how Navlinks is nested.

Top level:

```
<Router>
  <Main />
</Router>
```

Main:

```
<div>
  <Navbar />

  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  ...
```

And the Navlinks are inside Navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It might be worth noting that I am using React Router in my
>   application and clicking a link does trigger React Router.

This is your answer! React Router [sends updated props to your components](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/Route-props) when it routes to them. So when you trigger the link, it routes to the component with some props which triggers the render.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm still a little confused how render gets triggered for Navlink. Does everything within <Router></Router> get re-rendered when a Link is triggered? If so, how does it know to update since I'm using window.location instead of react-router's props.location?

Comment: The component attached to the matching `Route` will get new props passed into them. And it's still working because you are calling `isActive()` each time a render occurs. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you could post your `Router` it might help make it clearer.

Comment: Just updated to show where Router is in relation to everything. Good callout.

Comment: This is technically a different question, but this seems an appropriate place to ask it. In React, what are all the ways to trigger a re-render? I thought only a state change could do that. In this example, is it re-rendering because Router's state is changing, which causes all children to call render as well? I haven't seen anywhere that updating props by itself causes a render. Am I misunderstanding?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Looks like that's already been answered brilliantly here, for anyone interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617021/react-re-rendering-a-component-on-prop-update?rq=1